# React js , wanted to show the animation only on the added item "add to bag ' button

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, animation

I wanted to only show the animation in the "add to bag button only added item, but when I click the add to bag button all the other buttons[image] also display the animation but I wanted to just display the button animation only on the clicked button. Can anyone help me?

```js
<Table responsive>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>
                <p
                  className="p-2"
                  style={{ backgroundColor: "#F5F0E5", fontSize: "20px" }}
                >
                  SM
                </p>
              </th>
              {attributelist.map((attribute) => (
                <th key={variation.Name}>
                  <p
                    className="ml=5 p-2"
                    style={{ backgroundColor: "#F5F0E5", fontSize: "20px" }}
                  >
                    {attribute.Name}
                  </p>
                </th>
              ))}
              <th>
                <p
                  className="ml=5 p-2"
                  style={{ backgroundColor: "#F5F0E5", fontSize: "20px" }}
                >
                  Price
                </p>
              </th>
              <th className="text-center" />
            </tr>
          </thead>
          {variation.map((variations) => (
            <tbody key={variations.ID}>
              <tr>
                <td className="text-dark">{variations.VariationSKU}</td>
                {variations.Attributes.map((attribute) => (
                  <td key={attribute.ID} className="text-dark">
                    {attribute.Value}
                  </td>
                ))}
                <td className="text-dark">
                  {`RM${variations.Price.toFixed(2)}`}
                </td>
                <td>
                  <Button
                    id="Sproduct-btn"
                    className={`btn add-to-cart w-100 ${
                      addedId === variations.ID ? submitResponse.class : ""
                    }`}
                    data-toggle="tooltip"
                    type="button"
                    tag={!user ? Link : "a"}
                    to={!user ? "/login" : ""}
                    disabled={
                      submitResponse.openState ||
                      Status === "Inactive" ||
                      variationStatus === "Inactive" ||
                      Stock === 0 ||
                      variationStock === 0
                    }
                    style={{ fontSize: "15px", width: "30%" }}
                    {...(user && {
                      onClick: () =>
                        onSubmit(
                          setAddedId(variations.ID),
                          setResponse(addToCart(productid, variations.ID))
                        ),
                    })}
                  >
                    <div className="cart">
                      <div>
                        <div />
                        <div />
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="dots" />
                    {/* {variationStock === 0 || data.data.Stock === 0 ? (
                <div className="pl-2 default">SOLD OUT</div>
              ) : (
                <span className="pl-2 default">ADD TO BAG</span>
              )} */}
                    <span className="pl-2 default">{result}</span>
                    <div className="success">ADDED</div>
                    <div className="failed">
                      FAILED TO ADDED, PLEASE TRY AGAIN
                    </div>
                  </Button>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          ))}
        </Table>
```

above is my button code in the table

```js
 const [submitResponse, setSubmitResponse] = useState({
    class: "",
    openState: false,
  });
  const [response, setResponse] = useState();
  const [addedId, setAddedId] = useState();

  const onSubmit = () => {
    response
      .then(() => {
        // if success add to cart, process success animation
        setSubmitResponse({
          class: "added",
          openState: true,
        });
        setTimeout(() => {
          setSubmitResponse({
            class: "added txtState",
            openState: true,
          });
        }, 10);
        setTimeout(() => {
          setSubmitResponse({
            class: "added",
            openState: true,
          });
        }, 3000);
        // reset back to normal after 3.5s
        setTimeout(() => {
          setSubmitResponse({
            class: "",
            openState: false,
          });
        }, 3500);
      })

      .catch(() => {
        // if failed add to cart, process danger animation
        setSubmitResponse({
          class: "danger",
          openState: true,
        });
        setTimeout(() => {
          setSubmitResponse({
            class: "danger txtState",
            openState: true,
          });
        }, 10);
        setTimeout(() => {
          setSubmitResponse({
            class: "danger",
            openState: true,
          });
        }, 3000);

        // reset back to normal after 3.5s
        setTimeout(() => {
          setSubmitResponse({
            class: "",
            openState: false,
          });
        }, 3500);
      });
  };
```

above is my onSubmit ,function for animation display after item added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you set animation class to all button's in map :

```
className={`btn add-to-cart w-100 ${submitResponse.class}`}
```

you need use conditional statement to check which Button clicked. for example, you can define a state and set it added variations.ID.

```
className={'btn add-to-cart w-100 '+((addedId===variations.ID)?(submitResponse.class):'')}
```

**New Update :**

I have another idea for you :

> it's may need to change with you:

I change your table component :

```
<Table responsive>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>
                <p
                  className="p-2"
                  style={{ backgroundColor: "#F5F0E5", fontSize: "20px" }}
                >
                  SM
                </p>
              </th>
              {attributelist.map((attribute) => (
                <th key={variation.Name}>
                  <p
                    className="ml=5 p-2"
                    style={{ backgroundColor: "#F5F0E5", fontSize: "20px" }}
                  >
                    {attribute.Name}
                  </p>
                </th>
              ))}
              <th>
                <p
                  className="ml=5 p-2"
                  style={{ backgroundColor: "#F5F0E5", fontSize: "20px" }}
                >
                  Price
                </p>
              </th>
              <th className="text-center" />
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          {variation.map((variations) => (
              <TableRow variation={variations} />
          ))}
          </tbody>
          
        </Table>
```

And pass variation to each TableRow Component :

```
function TableRow({variation}) {


  const [submitResponse, setSubmitResponse] = useState({
    class: "",
    openState: false,
  });
  const [response, setResponse] = useState();

  const onSubmit = () => {
    response
      .then(() => {
        // if success add to cart, process success animation
        setSubmitResponse({
          class: "added",
          openState: true,
        });
        setTimeout(() => {
          setSubmitResponse({
            class: "added txtState",
            openState: true,
          });
        }, 10);
        setTimeout(() => {
          setSubmitResponse({
            class: "added",
            openState: true,
          });
        }, 3000);
        // reset back to normal after 3.5s
        setTimeout(() => {
          setSubmitResponse({
            class: "",
            openState: false,
          });
        }, 3500);
      })

      .catch(() => {
        // if failed add to cart, process danger animation
        setSubmitResponse({
          class: "danger",
          openState: true,
        });
        setTimeout(() => {
          setSubmitResponse({
            class: "danger txtState",
            openState: true,
          });
        }, 10);
        setTimeout(() => {
          setSubmitResponse({
            class: "danger",
            openState: true,
          });
        }, 3000);

        // reset back to normal after 3.5s
        setTimeout(() => {
          setSubmitResponse({
            class: "",
            openState: false,
          });
        }, 3500);
      });
  };


  return (<tr key={variations.ID}>
    <td className="text-dark">{variations.VariationSKU}</td>
    {variations.Attributes.map((attribute) => (
      <td key={attribute.ID} className="text-dark">
        {attribute.Value}
      </td>
    ))}
    <td className="text-dark">
      {`RM${variations.Price.toFixed(2)}`}
    </td>
    <td>
      <Button
        id="Sproduct-btn"
        className={`btn add-to-cart w-100 ${ submitResponse.class }`}
        data-toggle="tooltip"
        type="button"
        tag={!user ? Link : "a"}
        to={!user ? "/login" : ""}
        disabled={
          submitResponse.openState ||
          Status === "Inactive" ||
          variationStatus === "Inactive" ||
          Stock === 0 ||
          variationStock === 0
        }
        style={{ fontSize: "15px", width: "30%" }}
        {...(user && {
          onClick: () =>
            onSubmit(
              setResponse(addToCart(productid, variations.ID))
            ),
        })}
      >
        <div className="cart">
          <div>
            <div />
            <div />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="dots" />
        {/* {variationStock === 0 || data.data.Stock === 0 ? (
    <div className="pl-2 default">SOLD OUT</div>
  ) : (
    <span className="pl-2 default">ADD TO BAG</span>
  )} */}
        <span className="pl-2 default">{result}</span>
        <div className="success">ADDED</div>
        <div className="failed">
          FAILED TO ADDED, PLEASE TRY AGAIN
        </div>
      </Button>
    </td>
  </tr>)
}
```

Comment: HI have edit the code , is it wt u said

Comment: nearly, find a way to set selected item id, @Lucky

Comment: I don't get it can you help me please?

Comment: do you find answer of your question?